# set text in edttext without onclick

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, textwatcher

i'm trying to create an app that allows to convert text automatically when user write someting in keyborad without onclick action i want to getText from `editext` and set it in the same time after convert it, i tried to use `TextWatcher` but doesn't work .
here is my code :

```
EdiText text = v.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


          Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
                    converted = transliterator.transliterate(text.getText().toString());
    text.setText(converted);


            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should interrupt endless recursion!

```
class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        boolean changed = false;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (changed == true) {
                changed = false;
                return;
            }
            Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
            converted = transliterator.transliterate(s.toString());
            changed = true;
            text.setText(converted);
        }
    }

    text.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in this line :

```
converted = transliterator.transliterate(text.getText().toString());
text.setText(converted);
```

Instead of getting entered value form `text`, you should use `CharSequence s` of the method and after converting assign to `text` view.

Hope this will solve your problem.